# Camera in Android Oreo emulator

Tags: android, xamarin.android, camera

I'm running Visual Studio 2017 15.8.5 with Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo embulator version 27.2.9-4773671.

When I run the emulator, the computer's webcam does not activate. I only get some placeholder image.

Is there anything I can do or try to get the webcam to work from within the Android emulator?  I'm trying to test an app for scanning bar codes.

Thank you!

[image: Placeholder image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said by @dythim you click on Tools->Android-> AVD Manager then you chose the AVD to edit, if the camera feature is not on the first screen but you can see Show advanced Settings then click on the button to show advanced settings. For camera option choose Webcam0 as value to use for front and back cameras.

Answer (score 2):

The place to configure this is Tools -> Android -> Android Device Manager.